# Compactness is a topological property, proof without open covers

Tags: general-topology

An exercise in the book wants me to show that compactness is a topological property. This chapter is about topology of $R^n$ and we are working with an assumed metric. We haven't come to definition of topological spaces yet. We defined; open sets, closed sets, limit points, sequences, continuous functions, bounded sets, homeomorphisms and topological properties etc.

Here is the definition of compactness that the book uses.

**Defn:** A set $S$ is compact if every infinite sequence contained in $S$ has a limit point contained in $S$.

Now I am trying to prove the following.

---

**Proposition:** Compactness is a topological property.

I am trying to show that if $A \subset R^n$ is compact and there exists a homeomorphism $f: A \to B$, then $B$ is compact.

**Strategy:** Assume $A$ is compact, and $f$ is continuous with a continuous inverse. Go with proof by contradiction. Suppose $B$ is not compact. Then by Heine-Borel, $B$ is not (closed and bounded). So $B$ is either not closed or not bounded.

I showed that if $B$ is not closed, then $A$ is not compact and found a contradiction. I am trying to also show that if $B$ is not bounded, a contradiction arises. Then I think, I can conclude $B$ must be compact because all roads lead to a contradiction.

I need to show if $B$ is not bounded, a contradiction arises. Possible candidate is to show that $A$ is not compact, which contradicts the hypothesis.

Comment: $B$ is already compact from being equal to $f[A]$. A continuous image of compact is compact.

Comment: This is precisely what the OP wants to prove.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma That's what OP is trying to prove without using open covers.

Comment: You can also use that compact is the same as every infinite subset has a strong limit point, or every sequence has a convergent subsequence. (for metric spaces).

Comment: @meguli What is your definition of compactness? Are you required to prove this using Heine-Borel or is that just an idea?

Comment: It was my idea but now that I look back at it, I think going to the definition of compactness given in the book was way more useful, I'll edit and add the definition.

Comment: @meguli Yes, that would be helpful. When it comes to topology, it is useful to mention the definitions as different books use different equivalent conditions as definitions.

Comment: I think this definition with the theorem that continuous functions preserve limit points make the proof very easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ is closed then $B$ is closed because a homeomorphism is a closed map. Now we prove that $B$ is also bounded, by exploiting the fact that a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact if and only if is sequentially compact.

So, assume by contradiction that $B$ is not bounded. Then we can find a sequence $\{b_n \} \subset B$ such that $||b_n|| > n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. This sequence clearly does not admit any convergent subsequence.

On the other hand, we have $b_n = f(a_n)$ with $a_n \in A$, and by compactness of $A$ we can find a subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}$ of $\{a_n\}$ converging to $a \in A$. So, by continuity of $f$, the subsequence $\{b_{n_k}\} = \{f(a_{n_k})\}$ should converge to $f(a)$, contradiction.

Then $B$ is also bounded, hence compact by Heine-Borel.

Answer (score 4):

Let $(y_n)$ be an infinite sequence in $B.$ As $f$ is surjective, $$y_n=f(x_n)$$ where $(x_n)$ is s sequence in $A.$ Injectivity implies that $(x_n)$ is also an infinite sequence. Since, $A$ is compact, therefore $(x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence (denoted again by $(x_n)$, for convenience) in $A,$ to say $x$.
Thus, we have $$x_n \to x\text{ as } n\to \infty$$
Continuity of $f$ implies $$y_n=f(x_n) \to f(x)\text{ as } n\to \infty$$
Thus, $f(x)\in B$ is a limit point of $(y_n).$

Comment: Why would it be so that $(x_n)$ converges. Hint: it is not so.

Comment: @JensRenders Edited.

Answer (score 3):

You *have* to use open covers (for all spaces not just $\mathbb{R}^n$): a homeomorphism need not preserve boundedness at all.

Comment: But isn't it true that it will preserve total boundedness?

Comment: @AJY no, only uniformly continuous ones do.

Comment: Continuous function on a compact domain is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Then wouldn't that entail that homeomorphisms don't preserve compactness?

Comment: But for complete spaces, total boundedness is just "closure is compact"

Comment: I actually know that boundedness and closedness are not topological invariants. But I thought maybe if $A$ is compact and $f$ is continuous with continuous inverse, then I can show $B$ is bounded. $A$ is not an arbitrary domain anymore, it is known to be compact. Maybe that would let me, I thought, to work with boundedness.

Comment: @AJY of course homeomorphisms preserve compactness: you avn pull back covers.

Comment: If $f$ is a homeomorphism between a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$, a posteriori it *must* preserve boundedness.

Comment: @meguli: just use open covers, believe me.

Comment: But we haven't defined open covers yet. Should I skip this exercise?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes, I know that, but I see now how it doesn't entail the problem I thought it would.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I don't think this answers OP's question. This should be more of a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of compactness you have is what is in general topological spaces known as [sequential compactness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequentially_compact_space). It turns out that it is equivalent to compactness defined by open covers in metric spaces.

Now, the proof should use definition directly. If you have $f\colon A\to B$ a homeomorphism, and assume that $A$ is compact, then take any sequence $(b_n)$ in $B$. Sequence $(f^{-1}(b_n))$ is sequence in $A$, so it has convergent subsequence $(f^{-1}(b_{p(n)}))$ with limit $a$. Since $f$ is continuous, we have that $$f(a) = \lim_n f(f^{-1}(b_{p(n)})) = \lim_n b_{p(n)},$$ so $(b_n)$ has convergent subsequence.

Comment: Sequences in a compact set need to have a convergent subsequent because the sequence need to have a limit point in the set and a subsequent must converge to this limit point, this is how I got it.

Comment: @meguli, well yes, limit point of a sequence is the same thing as limit of convergent subsequence. Is that what you wanted to check?

Comment: I didn't know they are the same, book defines limit points without reference to convergent subsequences. But I needed a little thought to infer that they are the same after your answer. This different definitions for samely named concepts at different level of abstractions are what's tripping me.

Comment: @meguli, do you know how to rigorously show it now?

Comment: Yes,  by construcrion.